# Implement Ctrl+Enter to submit flag

Tags: feature-request, flags, keyboard-shortcuts

Just as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> submits an answer, it would be nice if it submitted a flag.

[image: Flag dialog]

Comment: tab, enter should work though?

Comment: @Shog9 and? using shift-enter works on everywhere else, it's not like it's a lot of work to add it ...

Comment: @Shog9: they do, and so does my muscle memory of Ctrl+Enter working everywhere else.